# Do we have any cli wallet in polkadot/substrate?

Tags: wallet

Do we have cli wallet like solana on polkadot or we just have polkadot extension to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no actively developed CLI wallet for polkadot/substrate. There is [subwallet](https://github.com/uni-arts-chain/subwallet) which is a CLI wallet with support for basic functionality (like transfers), but it seems to be unmaintained at this point.

If you are interested in creating a CLI wallet I would suggest that you use [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt) to build it.

Answer (score 4):

One option is `@polkadot/signer-cli` - see https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/tree/master/packages/signer-cli